# VB.NET Calculate the sum of value in column in DataTable from mySQL Database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datatable

Im a  bit confused. I have a mySQL database. It is hashed/encrypted. I used MySqlDataReader and my first query was:

```
SELECT SUM(column01) FROM dbtest.table01 WHERE column02 = '" & encrypt(selectedValue, salt) & "'
```

Problem is, the data inside the database is hashed/encrypted that is why it cannot compute the data. Now I switched to MySqlDataAdapter using this query I used in displaying the data in DataGridView(dehashed/decrypted data are displayed here):

```
SELECT column01 FROM dbtest.table01 WHERE column02 = '" & encrypt(_selectedValue, salt) & "'
```

Here is my code so far.

```
Dim dataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim dataTable As New DataTable
Dim bSource As New BindingSource

Try
   conn.Open()
   Dim query As String
   query = "SELECT column01 FROM dbtest.table01 WHERE column02 = '" & encrypt(_selectedValue, salt) & "'"
   command = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
   dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command
   dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable)
   bSource.DataSource = dataTable
   DataGridView_Moon.DataSource = bSource

   For i As Integer = 0 To dataTable.Rows.Count - 1
       dataTable.Rows(i)("column01") = decrypt(dataTable.Rows(i)("column01"), salt)
   Next

   conn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
Finally
   conn.Dispose()
End Try
```

If you could, pls place the totalValue into a messagebox. Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: calculate the sum of value that was fetched from mysql database

Comment: im thinking of... 1. fetch the encrypted/hashed data. 2, place the fetched data into a container, maybe in array or list. 3. decrypt/dehashed all the data. 4. compute the sum/total of the data.